# Are the contents of the daily achievement chest missable?

Tags: guild-wars-2

If I earn a chest for completing the daily achievements (pictured below) and don't open it before logging out, will the contents be lost? If not, can I open it with another character on my account?

[image: Daily achievement chest]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, the chest will not be lost when you log out**. I have left an unopened chest on the screen and it was still there the next day when I logged back on.

It is not possible to open the chest with another character, however, as only the character who completed the daily achievement will be able to see it.

Comment: The same applies with the monthly chest.

Comment: Most of it's content is "account bound" though, so you can transfer the content to another of your characters via the Bank.